# how to merge two pandas dataframe by column with camparing values from another column

Tags: pandas, merge

I've two data-frame, that I want to merge.

**df1**

```
sample,items,score
a,p1,0.9
b,p2,0.8
c,p3,0.6
```

**df2**

```
sample,items,score
d,p2,0.75
e,p3,0.7
f,p4,0.65
```

merge data-frame will be

```
sample,items,score,df_name
a,p1,0.9,df1
b,p2,0.8,df1
e,p3,0.7,df2
```

Condition:

- same items value columns compared with score. If score large then , large value data frame row will add.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` to align the dataframes, then use boolean indexing for in place modification:

```
df3 = df1[['items']].merge(df2, on='items', how='left')[df1.columns]

df1.loc[df1['score'].lt(df3['score'])] = df3
```

modified `df1`:

```
  sample items  score
0      a    p1    0.9
1      b    p2    0.8
2      e    p3    0.7
```

To add the indicator:

```
df1['df_name'] = 'df1'
df1.loc[df1['score'].lt(df3['score'])] = df3.assign(df_name='df2')
```

output:

```
  sample items  score df_name
0      a    p1    0.9     df1
1      b    p2    0.8     df1
2      e    p3    0.7     df2
```

Alternative using a temporary index:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('items')
df2 = df2.set_index('items')

df1['df_name'] = 'df1'
df1.loc[df1['score'].lt(df2['score'])] = df2.assign(df_name='df2')

df1 = df1.reset_index()
```